# Lenovo Ideapad p500 having Windows 8 booting issues. Boot repair pastebin included!

Tags: 13.10, windows-8, lenovo, ideapad

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10, and thought I properly set things up to dual boot into Windows 8, but I continually get .efi errors when I attempt to boot into Windows 8.

I installed Boot-Repair and used that to run the recommended fixes. It provided additional boot options within the GRUB2, but none (other than Ubuntu) are working.

Here's the file I pulled from Boot Repair that shows no errors!

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6321946/

I do appreciate any help - thank you!

Comment: the first entry is the on that should work. But Boot-Repair has run the file rename for those BIOS that only boot Windows. Not sure how it tells and I think it may rename some that do not need renaming. Try changing name back.   To undo & to rename files to their original names, you just need to tick the "Restore EFI backups" option of Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off `UEFI` which prevents Windows Os from booting.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Very quick fix. For any others that had this issue, I just switched to the BIOS and swapped over the booting mechanism to "Legacy" rather than UEFI. Once I did this, I could load right into Windows 8... and I just restarted and easily got back into Ubuntu. Thank you Avinash